# Extract translations from FormType in Symfony4

Tags: symfony4

Is it possible to extract placeholders and titles translations from FormType class in Symfony4 using console command php bin/console translation:update --force uz ?

```
  {
      $builder
          ->add('title', null, [
              'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'job_title_placeholder'],
              'attr_translation_parameters' => [
                  'job_title_placeholder' => 'What needs to be done',
              ],
          ])
          ->add('description', TextareaType::class, [
              'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'job_description_placeholder'],
              'attr_translation_parameters' => [
                  'job_description_placeholder' => 'Describe project details',
              ],
          ])
```

After successful extracting keys 'job_title_placeholder' and 'description_title_placeholder' are not added to translation file

Comment: the translation discovery essentially triggers when a (simple!) `trans` call is found *in code* (essentially `trans('string')` or in twig `'string'|trans`). you have just an array though.

Comment: So it is not posiible to collect translation variables from php classes ? No other way except of manually write keys in messages.xlf ?

Comment: it's always a heuristic at best. The core problem essentially is, if you have a function that receives a parameter `$key` and calls `$translator->trans($key)` it's really hard to find the places, where it is called. I mean, just take this: `user_call_func([$translator, 'tra'.'ns'], 'key')` - yes, it's quite artificial. What if the key is in a column in the database? the translation extraction is a heuristic that grabs the low-hanging fruit, but ultimately it fails. I tried to solve this problem once by adding never-called calls to the translator. but it's stupid.

Comment: my advice is to, yes, add all the translatable string, maybe even by hand, to the translation files and let the translator write helpful log messages when it can't find a translation. It's usually close enough. When you have enough tests, it will find most translation strings that way.